# Unable to create ActiveMQ Artemis instance in Windows

Tags: activemq-artemis

[image]

After uncompressing ActiveMQ Artemis I'm trying to run the `create` command inside the `bin` folder, but for some reason I'm not able to. Below the screenshots are provided.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first screenshot is of the normal Windows command-line and the second is of PowerShell. Did you try running `activemq create learningMq` from PowerShell? If so, what was the output? Also, can you print the value of `JAVA_HOME` from PowerShell itself?

Answer (score 0):

The error `JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set` is due to the wrong value of the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable for the user `asd`. It is `C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.10.7-hotspot\jdk-17` while it should be `C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.10.7-hotspot\` as defined in the list `System variables`.

You could fix it removing the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable from the list `User variables for asd` and restarting the shell before creating the service.

Comment: I have changed the path as mentioned by you and it resolved the JAVA_HOME warning error, but below that I'm still getting "unable to create the path learningMq".